# How do I install flatpak apps systemwide via command-line?

Tags: command-line, flatpak

I know that --user is enabled by default in Hera 5.1.7. But is it possible at all to install flatpaks system-wide for all users by command-line?

I have tried

```
$ sudo flatpak install --system com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects
Looking for matches…
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects’
```

whereas

```
$ flatpak install com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects
Looking for matches…
Found similar ref(s) for ‘com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects’ in remote ‘flathub’ (user).
```

Is system-wide installation disabled completely? Is there a way to enable it for command-line installs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add remotes separately for user and system installations.
This same thing caused me a bit of confusion.
The error message you received indicates that you probably just need to set up a system remote. To add Flathub as a system remote you would use the following command.

```
$ sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists --system flathub \
  https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Then just use `sudo` and the `--system` flag when running system-wide Flatpak commands.
For example, the following command installs PulseEffects system-wide.

```
$ sudo flatpak install --system flathub com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects
```

Once a system remote has been configured, Flatpaks can be installed system-wide directly from AppCenter.
Just note that it might require a restart for the option to appear.

Comment: Confirmed this works -- thank you!!